# pass array value in query post in wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress

Below code produce the below output -Array ( [0] => 393 [1] => 362 [2] => 361 ) in wordpress.

I want to convert this Array ( [0] => 393 [1] => 362 [2] => 361 ) into **array(393,362,361)** and I want to pass this array into wordpress query posts.

```
  <?php
                $getphotoidfromurl = 5;
                global $wpdb;
                // $sqlselque = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'metrodir_company_gallery' LIMIT 0 , 30";

                $db_item = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'metrodir_company_gallery' LIMIT 0 , 30"));
$r1=array();
                foreach ($db_item as $rs) {
                    //echo "hello";
//echo  $rs->post_id;
                    $getphotos = $rs->meta_value;

                    $rr = explode(",", $getphotos);

                 $getphotocount = count($rr);

                    if ($getphotoidfromurl == $getphotocount) {

                       $newgettwo = $rs->post_id;

                   // print_r($array);
                     array_push($r1, $newgettwo);

                    }
                }

                print_r($r1);
    exit;
                global $wp_query;




              query_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => array('company'),
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => $orderby,
                    'order' => $order,


                ));
```

So My wordpress query should look like this-

```
query_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => array('company'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'orderby' => $orderby,
                        'order' => $order,
                        'p'  => array(393,362,361)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply put $r1, because your resulted $r1 is fine,when we print_r($r1);
it show us array key index

```
         query_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => array('company'),
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => $orderby,
                    'order' => $order,
                    'p'  => $r1  //see here
```

e.g

```
$r1=array(393,362,361);
print_r($r1);
    //result        
     Array ( [0] => 393 [1] => 362 [2] => 361 )
```

Comment: Thanks, your are right.

I found the solution 'p' is used for single post type and post_in used for multiple ids that why I was not getting the right output after the passing $r1.